# Devise User Inheritance and user_signed_in? and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm using devise to help with my authentication and for various reasons I have a couple subclasses of the User model that helps separate the concerns for registration and some other business logic.

The subclasses of `User` are `Affiliate` and `Admin` (and I might have more in the future), all of which store all of the data in the User table (not separate tables).

All users can log in via the default `users` resource (`/users/sign_in`). However, this is where I'm having an issue.

If the user signs in via the `/users/sign_in` resource I can access the `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` helper and then access any other Active Record associations. This is what I want! Woo hoo! This works great.

However, the same is not true of a user who signs up as an `Affiliate`. Since devise automatically logs the user in (which I DO want) I expect that `user_signed_in?` to equal `true` and `current_user` to be the user that just signed in. This is not the case when a user signs up via the `/affiliate/sign_up` resource.

On the `Affiliate` model (remember, it subclasses user like such `class Affiliate < User`) I have generated (through devise) a separate set of  controller/views for sign_up  so I can customize this process a bit (as the sign_up process is a bit more customized for this particular type of user). When the user signs up via this resource `/affiliate/sign_up` the affiliate is then signed up, but NOW, the `current_user` is `nil` and `user_signed_in?` is `false`. But, the helpers `current_affiliate` is a hydrated object and `affiliate_signed_in?` is true.

What I want to do is be able to access ONE type of helper - the `user_signed_in?` helper and the `current_user` helper not the child `affiliate_signed_in?` and `current_affiliate`.  I'd like to access: `current_user` and `user_signed_in` only. Seeing that `Affiliate` subclasses `User`, why doesn't `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` returned the current user (aka: the `Affiliate`)? Why do the `current_affiliate` and `affiliate_signed_in?` helpers work, but not the `user`-esque ones not?

Is there a way to make the framework always use `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` helpers since everything is subclassing the `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

The way you set it up, it seems that you are able to log in as both a user and an affiliate at the same time. That means, that at a given moment there could be a current_user and a current_affiliate. If you want it to be current_user all the time, you can override the Devise helpers. But you have to make sure that a there can only be a user OR an affiliate logged in, through one session. Else Devise has no way of knowing which object to return for current_user.